# Adding captcha to drupal 7 entityforms

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, captcha

I need to add a captcha to a form created with entityforms in drupal 7. I can't find any info on how to do this. Can anyone tell me how this is done?

Answer (score 1):

Try this module it will works...

https://drupal.org/project/captcha

Answer (score 1):

1. Install module https://drupal.org/project/captcha
2. Goto entityform form.
3. On firebug view form source. And copy value from field: `<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="contact_entityform_edit_form">`
4. Goto /admin/config/people/captcha and FORM_ID from early copyed value.

Answer (score 0):

Another useful Module is the [Spamicide](https://drupal.org/project/spamicide) Module.

> Spamicide adds an input field to each form then hides it with css, when spam bots fill in the field the form is discarded.

You can turn on this functionality on every Form in Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

To add a CAPTCHA to an [Entityform Type](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform) in Drupal:

1. Install or enable the contributed [Captcha](https://drupal.org/project/captcha) module.
2. Determine which Entityform Type(s) you want a CAPTCHA added to:

   Admin > Structure > Entityform Types
   `admin/structure/entityform_types`
3. From the list of Entityform Types, copy the *Machine Name* of the Entityform Type (e.g. `contact_us`).
4. Configure the Captcha module:

   Admin > Configuration > People > CAPTCHA
   `admin/config/people/captcha`
5. Within the Form Protection fieldset, add the *Machine Name** of the Entityform Type as the Form ID value.

   > *Note: the Form ID expected by the Captcha module is the Entityform Type machine name appended with the string of text `_entityform_edit_form`.
   >
   > For instance, if your Entityform Type machine name is `contact_us`, the complete Form ID would be `contact_us_entityform_edit_form`.

   You can verify this by viewing the HTML source of an Entityform Type and cross-referencing the form's ID attribute:

   `<form class="entityform" id="contact-us-entityform-edit-form" ...>`

   Keep in mind, the actual value has hyphens replaced with underscores, as common in Drupal.
6. Select the appropriate Challenge Type or use the defaults.
7. Save the Captcha configuration changes.

To verify the CAPTCHA has been successfully added, open a private browsing session (e.g. a Chrome Incognito window) and view the Entityform Type, or simply view the form while logged-out of Drupal.